# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘msilib’

Tags: django, heroku

After I deployed my Django project in Heroku for the first time and clicked view, I got this error. when I looked up this module it says it is depreciated. I tried pycopy-msilib but it is asking for setup.py which I can’t find how it’s made

Any advice or directions would be appreciated. Thank You

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 556, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/mysite/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('', include('core.urls')),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/core/urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .views.managment_view import ManagmentPageView, UpdateCallItem, UpdateCallist,UpdateCashbal
  File "/app/core/views/managment_view.py", line 15, in <module>
    from core.serialize import CallListSerializer
  File "/app/core/serialize.py", line 3, in <module>
    from msilib.schema import Class

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'msilib'
```

```
My requirment.txt: 
APScheduler==3.8.1
arabic-reshaper==2.1.3
asgiref==3.4.1
asn1crypto==1.5.1
Brotli==1.0.9
certifi==2022.5.18.1
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==37.0.2
cssselect2==0.6.0
defusedxml==0.7.1
diff-match-patch==20200713
dj-database-url==1.0.0
Django==3.2.9
django-appconf==1.0.5
django-compressor==4.0
django-easy-pdf3==0.1.4
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-import-export==2.6.1
django-wkhtmltopdf==3.4.0
djangorestframework==3.12.4
djangorestframework-datatables==0.7.0
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fonttools==4.33.3
future==0.18.2
html5lib==1.1
idna==3.3
lxml==4.9.0
MarkupPy==1.14
numpy==1.22.3
odfpy==1.4.1
openpyxl==3.0.9
oscrypto==1.3.0
pandas==1.4.2
Pillow==9.1.1
psycopg2==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
pydyf==0.2.0
pyHanko==0.13.1
pyhanko-certvalidator==0.19.5
PyPDF3==1.0.6
pyphen==0.12.0
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
PyYAML==6.0
qrcode==7.3.1
rcssmin==1.1.0
reportlab==3.6.10
requests==2.28.0
rjsmin==1.2.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
svglib==1.3.0
tablib==3.1.0
tinycss2==1.1.1
tqdm==4.64.0
tzdata==2021.5
tzlocal==4.1
uritools==4.0.0
urllib3==1.26.9
weasyprint==55.0
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==6.2.0
xhtml2pdf==0.2.7
xlrd==2.0.1
xlwt==1.3.0
zopfli==0.2.1
```

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Why do you expect this library to be available? Did you depend on it yourself, or is it a transitive dependency? Please show your `requirements.txt`, `setup.py`, or `Pipfile`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean  transitive dependency but I haven't used this module anywhere in this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all for your Response and sorry for wasting your time but the cause if this problem was my negligence. In VSCode when you type function name which you must import, and you click ctrl+. to get the options for the import. I did this for several functions without checking the options since it worked previously

That was the cause of this problem.

I am sorry for taking your time and Thank You for your Response

Comment: Morning @peter! Please consider this as an answering area only. It is not right to use this area to type a comment on the responses in order not to confuse that others who may read your question and the answers below. If you need to thank someone on his answer, please do it as a comment on his answer directly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

msilib is not mentioned in your requirements you have to make pip freeze to add all requirements to your file but ass a work around you can use